# Trying to redirect from non-https to https but only on www subdomain in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to create an HTACCESS file that will have the following rules below. I'm trying to use various online guides to piece together a single htaccess file, but I'm having an issue with one little bit.

I want to redirect from http to https.
I want to redirect from non-www to www.
I want to be able to follow any subdomains on standard http.

The last part is the part I'm strugglign with. The other two rules work fine. But when I try to visit http://demo.example.com, it redirects to https which I don't want it to do.

How can I create some kind of IF statement or make this work?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this single rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to keep this rule as your **top rule** and test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

**Details:**

There are 4 lines in the rule body. Here are details:

1. Line 1 is an `OR` condition that returns true if `HTTPS` is not on
2. Line 2 is another condition that returns true is there is no `www` in domain name. One of first 2 conditions must be true for this rule.
3. Line 3 is another condition that returns true if current domain name is `www.example.com` or `example.com` as starting `wwww` is optional. It also captures `example.com` in back-reference `%1`
4. Line 4 is `RewriteRule` that redirects to `https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI}` where `%{REQUEST_URI}` is current request URI and `%1` is value `example.com` we capture in line 3.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work fine, but can you please try and explain what's different?

Comment: Well there are lots of differences between what I had, and what you have. I was hoping you could explain each line and parameter to explain why this works...

Comment: Yes it did, thanks for detailing it thoroughly. Very useful.